# Getting SharedPreferences in Non-Activity class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have the following class:

```
public class UserPref {
    Context context;

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    public SessionUtils(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error on `getPreferences()`:

> Cannot resolve method 'getPreferences(int)'

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you're missing "key": `getPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's like

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

More about it [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)