# SharedPreferences Save value of Int in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, int, save, sharedpreferences

I try to save the value of an int displayed in a TextView using SharedPreferences, it can't work at all. I did a simple small example of code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button search;
TextView tvRing;
int redRing;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radar);
    tvRing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ring);

    int someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
    tvRing.setText("Objects found : " + String.valueOf(someint));

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addRing();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("someint", redRing);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
}

public void addRing() {
    redRing++;
}
}
```

Thank u all for yo help.

Comment: Your code seems fine, what do you mean by "cant work at all"?

Comment: I wanna save the value of the TextView because the int increase when user click the button but if I quit the app and come back again, the value of the TextView return to the default value of 0. Can't work at all for save the data I mean

Comment: Where are you using someint?

Comment: Yes maybe I got to use the value of someint in the TextView ?

Comment: Check again my answer, i made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained where I made changes

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button search;
    TextView tvRing;

    //Making sharedpreferences and integers global for ease of use
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private int redRing, someint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radar);
        tvRing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ring);

        //Someint default value is 0 if not ever saved before
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
        tvRing.setText("Objects found : " + String.valueOf(someint));

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Load the lates someint in onclick
                someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);

                //redring is the dummy integer to increment someint
                redRing=someint+1;
                //Save the incremented value
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt("someint", redRing);
                editor.commit();

                //To show the latest number on the tv
                lastNumber();
            }
        });
    }


    public void lastNumber() {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
        tvRing.setText("Objects found : " + String.valueOf(someint));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, there's save of value but the problem is if I quit the app and click again on the button search, the TextView start to 0 again but before click I can see the last number

Comment: Check this out.

Comment: I deleted redundant final sharedpreferences call in lastNumber method. Sorry.

Comment: With this edit, app will always remember the last number in tv. And as you click on that search button the number in tv will be incremented. Is this what you want? Or you just want to start from 0 all the time?

Comment: But my code isnt really like that in my app, I just simplified it, maybe I got to change something. I explain it: I have a class where I created Ring object, the addRing() method is on this class where the redRing int variable increase. Then I have an activity with the button search, I click on it and create a new Ring and I call addRing() method so the user can find some new Ring objects. Then I have another activity for display the stock of each different rings because there's different colors of rings. Do u think I got to change something in order to do the same thing but with 2 activities?

Comment: You can change someint as dummy and save redRing int in sharedpreferences maybe. I can't be sure. You should try. And you can, for example load redRing int everywhere using:
 prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        redRing = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);

Of course you have to make sharedpreferences global as well if you use like this. 
private SharedPreferences prefs;

Comment: Yes ok but the SharedPreferences need a Context in order to work, and in my class Ring I have,'t no context because I just created the object Ring and add some methods, there's no layout because it's not an activity. Maybe I can post a new question, u can check it?

Comment: I used "import static" in order to share the value of redRing to my Activity1

Comment: So, with importing is it working? If not, I would suggest you to search this website first about the issue, and if you cannot find anything then post your question.

Comment: There are some posts about it. Some of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360999/getting-sharedpreferences-in-non-activity-class

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491287/android-how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-non-activity-class

Comment: Ok I did something, it seems working, but I got to add all variables and test it again, I will do it tomorrow, if I have an issue I will post a new question about it. Thank u so much

Comment: I don't know what cause it but sometimes there's a reset, the sum come back to 0 if I quit the app but not everytime, it's strange, I will post a question tomorrow maybe

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("someint", redRing);
        editor.apply();
```

and you are never using "someint", use

```
tvRing.setText(String.valueOf(someint));
```

Comment: You are never using "someint"

Comment: place it below the line you assign someint

Comment: Ok it's working, the value of the int was saved in SharedPreferences but now on the TextView the value doesn't increase when I click the button Search, however if I quit the app and I come back again on my app the TextView is updated, do u know why?

Comment: I made an edit of my post with yo advices, can u check what's wrong?

Comment: Update this public void addRing() {
    redRing++; tvRing.setText(String.valueOf(redRing));
}

Comment: Yes I tried it but something wrong, because if I quit the app, I just retrieve the number of click I did on the button last time I was on the app and not everytime, it's difficult to explain but it's not working as well

Comment: Hi Hasan, I did a new question here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859463/sharedpreferences-save-value-of-int-in-a-textview-of-another-activity Can u check where's there's the wrong code please?