# SharedPreferences Save value of Int in a TextView of another activity

Tags: android, textview, int, save, sharedpreferences

I try to save the value of an int "redRing" from the class "Ring" displayed in a TextView of another activity using SharedPreferences, it can work but not everytime, sometimes there's a reset of the value of my int if I quit the app and come back again in my app but not everytime. I did a simple small example of code if someone can try to say me what's wrong with my code?

1) The class Ring :

```
public class Ring { // User search rings with different colors

public static int color;
public static int redRing, greenRing, nbRing, somment, someGreen, someRing;
public static TextView tvNbRing, tvRingColor;
// Constuctor
public Ring(int c) { this.color = c; }
// Getter
public int getColor() { return this.color; }

public void setColor(int dice) { // For the example there’s 2 colors
    dice = (int)(Math.random()*2+1);
    this.color = dice;
    if(this.color == 1) { // If 1 so user find a red ring
        redRing = someint + 1;
        tvRingColor.setText("It's a red ring");
    }
    if(this.color == 2) {
        greenRing = someGreen + 1; // I add the green color
        tvRingColor.setText("It's a green ring");
    }
}

public int setNbRingFind() { // Nb = Number
    int rings = (int)(Math.random()*2+0); // User can find 0 or 1 ring
    Ring r = new Ring(this.color);
    if(rings>0) {
        nbRing = someRing + 1;
        tvNbRing.setText("You find " + rings + " ring");
        r.setColor(this.color);
    } else { tvNbRing.setText("Nothing find, try again"); }
        return rings;
}
}
```

2) Activity1 : Main

```
import static fr.ringshared.Ring.tvNbRing;
import static fr.ringshared.Ring.tvRingColor;
import static fr.ringshared.Ring.redRing;
import static fr.ringshared.Ring.someint;
import static fr.save.sharedpreferences.Ring.greenRing;
import static fr.save.sharedpreferences.Ring.nbRing;
import static fr.save.sharedpreferences.Ring.someGreen;
import static fr.save.sharedpreferences.Ring.someRing;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button search, stock, useRing;
TextView tvRing;
int x = 0;
Ring r = new Ring(x); // Create a Ring with a x color
private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radar);
    stock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capsules);
    useRing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.useRing);
    tvRing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ring);
    tvNbRing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNbRing);
    tvRingColor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRingColor);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
    someGreen = prefs.getInt("someGreen", 0);
    someRing = prefs.getInt("someRing", 0);
    tvRing.setText("Objets trouvés : " + String.valueOf(someRing));

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
            someGreen = prefs.getInt("someGreen", 0);
            someRing = prefs.getInt("someRing", 0);
            addRing();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("someint", redRing);
            editor.putInt("someGreen", greenRing);
            editor.putInt("someRing", bring);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            lastNumber();
        }
    });

    stock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentStock = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StockActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentStock);
        }
    });
}

public void addRing() { // I use a method from the class Ring
    r.setNbRingFind();
}

public void lastNumber(){
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
    someGreen = prefs.getInt("someGreen", 0);
    someRing = prefs.getInt("someRing", 0);
    tvRing.setText("Objects find : " + String.valueOf(someint));
}
}
```

3) Activity2 : StockActivity

```
import static fr.ringshared.Ring.someint;
import static fr.save.sharedpreferences.Ring.someGreen;
import static fr.save.sharedpreferences.Ring.someRing;

public class StockActivity extends Activity {

TextView tvRing2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capsules);

    tvRing2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ring2);
    tvGreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.green);
    tvTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

    tvRing2.setText("Red rings find : " + String.valueOf(someint));
    tvGreen.setText("Green rings find " + String.valueOf(someGreen));
    tvTotal.setText("All rings find : " + String.valueOf(someRing));
}
}
```

If someone can help me to find where my code has a problem because in logical no error show, just during running, sometimes the value of the int "redRing" or "someint" has resetted to 0 instead of keep the last number of his value.

Comment: Well, I can't understand what the problem is. I guess it is beyond my knowledge. Maybe you should make a button to check what is stored in sharedpreferences step by step when you are using the app. In the onclick:
prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(someint));

With such a button, you can see what is in sharedpreferences in the console.

Comment: Ok thank u Hasan, I will try, I know this piece of code is too longer for ask a question, thank u for all u help

Comment: I see in the console the same value of someint than in the TextView. If u want u could try to do it in a new project and see what I mean

Comment: Ok. I'll try to check it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank u Hasan, another member here said that : Your redRing value return 0 because SharedPreferences not found key. You can change "sharedPreferences" to "file. sharedPreferences.myapp" and "someint" to "myapp.key.someint"

Comment: But I don't really understand how to create this file

Comment: I have got some ideas as to why your sharedpreferences gets reset. Make sure you don't have **2 sharedpreferences editors** that simultaneously modify the same sharedpereferences.

And try updating here.

`search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
         
editor.clear();

   editor.putInt("someint", redRing);
editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            lastNumber();`

And I don't know what he means. I hope he explains.

Comment: Ok I try, so I don't use this instruction on the search button click : someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0); ? I can delete it ?

Comment: No, you should keep it. Sorry, I forgot to add it.
    `search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0);
            addRing();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 
editor.clear(); 
editor.putInt("someint", redRing); 
editor.apply(); 
editor.commit(); 
lastNumber();}`

Comment: I tried but it's always the same issue, it get resetted. I checked too for the editor and I just the editor in the search button onClick. Maybe there's a problem with the prefs.getInt() because I write this instruction 3 times on my code. (One is in onCreate(), Two is in onClick of search Button and Three is on the lastNumber() method). Do u think it can cause an issue?

Comment: It resetted again at anytime, I can't understand why it rested without logic reason

Comment: No. getInt only loads what is inside sharedpreferences. But you can try deleting them if you want. I actually suspect from this method: `public void setColor(int dice) { 
    dice = (int)(Math.random()*2+1);
    this.color = dice;
    if(this.color == 1) { // If 1 so user find a red ring
        redRing = someint + 1;
        tvRingColor.setText("It's a red ring");
    }
    if(this.color == 2) {
        redRing = someint + 1;
        tvRingColor.setText("It's a green ring");
    }`

What is the default value of the someint here? I think, it can be zero. But, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok I just updated my code here on my first post, I add 2 variables because I use this code for test it with yo comments. Maybe it's because I use the same editor for save this 3 values?

Comment: oh yes u're right on my Ring class the default value of someint should be 0 because I don't put a default value for someint in this class.

Comment: `editor.putInt("someint", redRing);` With this code in search button, everytime you click on search, you are changing the value of someint with redRing value. You know this right?

Comment: Yes u're right, so I got to do this instruction only if redRing == 0 ? Else what can I write? editor.putInt("someone", someint); ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you want to do. Right now, with this code, you save redRing value as someint and you show it in a textview in activity1 main.

Comment: It's for show at the user how many rings he has found, because he can use these rings for something else after on the game. But I changed a little bit the code if u want to see it on my first question above.

Comment: I think, you should examine your app in your free time step by step maybe by commenting what code does what to see the whole. If I wanted to do what you ask, I would try to assign a Boolean in setNbRingFind(); and assign that Boolean true if user finds a ring, and assign false otherwise. Then reach that Boolean in onclick of search button. And if true increment an int value by one and save it to sharedpreferences.

Comment: Ok thank u Hasan for yo comments, it helps me a lot.

Comment: Just one thing about it. If I add a button called "useRing" for decrease the number of rings found, I got to write this instructions for example : someint = prefs.getInt("someint", 0); someint = someint - 1;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt("someone", someint);
                editor.commit();
                lastNumber();    ?

Comment: Do u think it will work because I use the same Editor than increase it?

Comment: It'll work, if not, you can make an editor2 like: `SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = prefs.edit();`
For example, in this code `prefs.getInt("someint", 0);` "someint" means keycode to the int value. If you want to decrease the same keycode(someint), you should edit the same keycode in the editor. In your comment, it is not someint, it is someone. I don't know if that's a typo.

Comment: Ok so for each same value like someint I got to use the same editor, but if I have different int I got to make a new editor for each different int, like someGreen int and someRing int, I added these variables on my code above

Comment: No. I'm talking about the key where your int stored. 'prefs.getInt("someint", 0);' here you save 0 with "someint" key. To edit it: 'SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); editor.putInt("someint", Your new int value)' .You see I use the same key(someint) to edit that variable with the editor. First you write a codename for your value between " ". Then u say a value.

Comment: Read a tutorial about sharedpreferences please.

Comment: I use different keys for each value that I wanna save with the same editor. Ok if u have a good tutorial to advice me? Because I just find tutorial for explain simple things.

Comment: Yes that's right. Well, I don't remember a good tutorial now :)

Comment: Ok no problem, thank u for all yo helps. After 2 days I will show my app to my school for validate my training, I miss time but thanks for everything, u help me a lot, if u need something don't hesitate to come to me if I can help u I will too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143910/discussion-between-hasan-saykin-and-ghiggz-pikkoro).

Answer (score 1):

`getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` call from a Context. If you use context from activity SharedPreferences maybe not found key. You can try `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`

Comment: I add it on the MainActivity?

Comment: It's the same issue, sometimes the sum of the redRing are reset to 0, I don't know why

Comment: Your redRing value return 0 because SharedPreferences not found key. You can change "sharedPreferences" to "file. sharedPreferences.myapp" and "someint" to "myapp.key.someint".

Comment: Ok, but can u write a full example of this instruction because I don't understand well. Thank u

Comment: Can u develop yo comment or make an answer please ?